# Prefill contact form with javascript and hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form

I have been doing a ton of searching to see how to get this to work. I found this code which is close but I cannot figure out how to get the hashtag data from the url instead of pre-entering it into the code. Basically I want to link to something that a customer is inquiring about by using `myurl.com/contactus/#refnumber=numberhere` and then have it fill it in on the form based on the id.

This snippet I found also has it looking for an extra & parameter which I do not need. ANy help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
var hash = '#refnumber=test'

var hashParams = hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the #
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
```

I seem to have figured it out after some more online searching and a bit of tinkering: I do wonder if that will work in most browsers. Will have to test!

```
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#refnumber=', ''); // get hash and replace the '#' (hash) tag
document.getElementById('refnumber').value = hash; // add value to input
```

Comment: Check [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) on load and listen to [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) event?

Comment: Sorry I am not very good at all with javascript. How would I implement that so var hah will out put with the refnumber=number from the url and then it can take that and fill in ID on the form which the rest does perfectly with the test already put prefilled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you want is:

```
var hash = location.hash
```

To simplify your code a little:

```
var hash = location.hash
var p = hash.substr(1).split('=');
document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks I couldn't get that one to work but the one I listed in my updated topic works perfectly for me. Thanks for your time .. I appreciate everyones help here as always!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I seem to have figured it out after some more searching and tinkering.

var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#refnumber=', ''); // get hash and replace the '#' (hash) tag
document.getElementById('refnumber').value = hash; // add value to input